# Jquery Id parameter get wrong

Tags: c#, jquery, html

I cannot see what is wrong here:

Javascript

```
function showDialogBox(dialogText, atomicId) {

    if (dialogText.text == "")
    {
        dialogText = "¿Do you want to continue?";
    }

    if ($('#' + atomicId).text() != "") 
    {
        return confirm(dialogText);
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The Label HTML

```
<asp:Label ID="AtomicId" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="datalabel DHidden" />
```

I checked atomicId param and its "AtomicId" string, but when I check $('#' + atomicId).text, it returns:
[alert($('#' + atomicId).text);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIuvR.jpg)

What!!??. The text of the Label AtomicId is supposed to be empty the first call.

I updated it with the rest of my code where I call the function. Anyway Shobhit Walia solved it.

```
    protected void GridDecisionsView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
        e.Row.Cells[1].Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
        e.Row.Cells[2].Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
        e.Row.Cells[3].Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");

        if (e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(showDialogBox('" + getDialogString() + "', '" + AtomicId.ID + "')){" 
                                + CSM.GetPostBackEventReference((Control)sender, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()) + "}"); 
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: How you calling `showDialogBox()`?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why `$('#' + atomicId)` instead of `$("#AtomicId")` ? Why is the selector parametric?

Comment: I am just trying to to set a confirm dialog for all my webforms. I used $('#' + atomicId) because the ID may change depending of the webform loaded. In this case is similar to the Id name of the Label, that's all. I will update it with the code behind where I call the function.

Comment: Solved by Shobhit Walia...Thanks to all for your time and interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with these

```
function showDialogBox(dialogText, atomicId) {

if (dialogText == "")
{
    dialogText = "¿Do you want to continue?";
}

if ($('#' + atomicId).text() != "")
{
   return confirm(dialogText);
}

}
```

Comment: Yeah +1 for you...solved it and working fine. I did not realised...totally asleep